# Rails controller querying by date comparison

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am using model's scope to make filter for my queries.

Something like this where I am filtering all x workers belonging to a company_id

```
scope :company_id, -> (company_id) { where company_id: company_id }
```

But now I am making a more complex query. Let's say for example I have the model Worker and I want to query the workers assigned to a company_id from the latest 5 days.

So in my models I created this filter scope:

```
scope :latest, -> (created_at) { where created_at: >= Time.now - 5.day}

@company = Company.find(params[:id])
@workers = Worker.company_id(@company.id).latest(??)
```

Which would be the syntax or paramter for the latest's filter? If I leave it empty it gives me a syntax error.

Comment: **I want to query the workers assigned to a `company_id` from the latest 5 days** - what if a worker exists who was having `123` in company_id and just before 2 days back its value got changed to the company_id against which you want to search ?

Comment: mmm I should check also updated_at then right? Well it hasnt to be perfect anyway, I am learning RoR and just playing with the queries :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two notes: such more complex query conditions cannot be written using symbols, you have to use string notation instead. And, secondly, a scope does not need to have a parameter, your `latest` scope is one of them, as you simply compare the *database* `created_at` time with the current time shifted by 5 days. So, the correct scope should be something like:

```
scope :latest, -> { where("created_at >= ?", Time.now - 5.days) }
```

and you call it simply:

```
@workers = Worker.company_id(@company.id).latest
```

Answer (score 1):

The ***latest*** scope doesn't need a parameter. The below should work.

```
scope :latest, -> { where("created_at >= ?", Time.now - 5.days)}
```

so that you can just do

```
@workers = Worker.company_id(@company.id).latest
```

Comment: Thanks! that's it, When I tried without parameters I also had a syntax error with the comparison

Answer (score -2):

If I understand correctly, you don't need to pass an argument to that scope.

```
scope :latest, -> { where created_at: >= Time.now - 5.day}
```